# Difference between "at any instant be sown" and "be sown at any instant"

Tags: difference, sentence-choice

> The children, small seeds, might **at any instant be sown** to all the
>   Martian climes.

Why not the sentence be written as:

> The children, small seeds, might **be sown at any instant** to all the
>   Martian climes.

what is the difference between these sentences?
***Source:***
(***Dark they were , and golden eyed by Ray Bradbury)***

Comment: No difference in meaning, just a difference in how the sentence flows, with perhaps a subtle shift in emphasis.

Comment: @J.R. The flow is worth the second way. Should there not be a comma before and after "**at any instant**" when it's inserted that way? By the way, you can also say, "**The children, small seeds, might be sown to all the Martian climes at any instant.**"

Comment: @Sovereign - No, I wouldn’t put a comma there. To M.Naeem Ahmad: You really should tell us where you found this sentence. [Here’s why](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source).

Comment: @SovereignSun Either way can be elegant; the main reason for choosing the first one would be to avoid separating the verb and "to all the Martian climes". Your suggestion also achieves that, but it also moves "at any instant" to the more salient end position, which the author probably intended for "climes" (a striking word to complete a poetic sentence).

Comment: @J.R.I've mentioned the source,please make it clear now.

Answer (score 1):

"at any moment" is an adverbial phrase. There is considerable latitude in the placement of adverbs, which varies depending on the type of adverb. This one is an [adverb of time](https://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/adverbs-time/): these can be placed

- at the end: this is a neutral position
- at the start: this emphasises the adverb
- before the verb: this is usually done for literary effect.

In the original text that you quoted, the adverb is positioned before the verb, so we assume that it was done for literary effect.

[This article](https://staff.washington.edu/marynell/grammar/AdverbPl.html) suggests that it is possible to put an adverb of time after a **be** verb:

> The children, small seeds, might be **at any instant** sown to all the Martian climes.

I cannot find anything suggesting that an adverb can be placed after the main verb, as it is in your proposed version of your sentence. That's not to say that it's wrong, but it would very unusual and people would wonder why you did it that way.

Comment: Your version is less natural than Bradbury's (though both are uncommon compared to positioning the phrase at the end)

Comment: @BenVoigt: I am not surprised: Ray Bradbury was a better writer than I will ever be. I never suggested that the post-**be** version was better: I merely said that it is possible,